# Using redirect_to with a specific ActiveRecord object to create a link to that object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through Michael Hartl's tutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/. It's basically a message board app where Users can post Messages and others can leave Replies.  Right now I'm creating `Users`. Inside the `UsersController` things look like this:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @user = User.new
      end

      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end

      def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
          flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
          redirect_to @user
        else
          render 'new'
        end    
      end
    end
```

The author says that the following lines are equivalent. Which makes sense to me:

```
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    is equivalent to
    @user = User.new(name: "Foo Bar", email: "foo@invalid",
             password: "foo", password_confirmation: "bar")
```

`redirect_to @user` redirects to `show.html.erb`. How exactly does that work? How does it know to go to `show.html.erb`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is all handled through the magic of Rail's restful routing. Specifically, there's a convention that doing a `redirect_to` a specific object goes to the `show` page for that object. Rails knows that `@user` is an active record object, so it interprets that as knowing you want to go to the show page for the object.

Here's some detail from the appropriate section of the [Rails Guide - Rails Routing from the Outside In.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects):

```
# If you wanted to link to just a magazine, you could leave out the
# Array:

<%= link_to "Magazine details", @magazine %>

# This allows you to treat instances of your models as URLs, and is a
# key advantage to using the resourceful style.
```

Basically, using restful resources in your `routes.rb` file gives you 'shortcuts' for creating url's directly out of ActiveRecord objects.

Answer (score 2):

When you take a look of  the [source code](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to) of `redirect_to`, you will notice that finally, it will return `redirect_to_full_url(url_for(options), status),` try to call the `url_for` function with an object, suppose you have an object is **@article**, url_for(@article), it will return like this:"http://localhost:3000/articles/11", that's will be a new request to this URL, then in your routing, you can also check the routes in your console by type in:

> `rake routes`
>
> `article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show`

so that's why the `redirect_to @article` will to go `SHOW` action, and render in `show.html.erb`. Hope answered your question.

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest reading about Resource routing http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html .